# How can mono social icon work without a class per icon?

Tags: css, fonts, icons

I'm wondering how [Mono Social Icons](http://drinchev.github.io/monosocialiconsfont/) displays the correct icon.

Other with other font icon sets you need to add a class name, which loads an utf-8 character in `:after`.

However this is not the case with mono social icons. You simply need to add the icon as text and the correct icon is shown. This is done minimal CSS.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Mono Social Icons Font';
    src: url('MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot');
    src: url('MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.woff') format('woff'),
         url('MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.svg#MonoSocialIconsFont') format('svg');
    src: url('MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.symbol {
    font-family: 'Mono Social Icons Font';
}
```

Than I can use the font as

```
<span class='symbol'>facebook</span>
```

I'm completely mystified in how on how Mono Social Icons works under the hood.

Does someone know how this is achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to OpenType fonts: fonts are immensely complex applications, and have been for decades now, being pretty much nothing like what you're probably thinking of when you think of a font (e.g. "one picture for each letter"). What you're seeing is basic substitution functionality.

It works the same way that good fonts replace "f" + "i" with a ligature "ﬁ", and fonts like http://sansbullshitsans.com do full-word substitutions: the text engine follows the font's instructions on how to style the string "whatever", and sees that the font contains a [GSUB table](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/gsub.htm) for substitution rules. It consults that table (simplified, because each script and language can have different rules, and one font can support hundreds of those), and sees a [ligature substitution rule](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/gsub.htm#LS) that needs to be applied:

```
{w,h,a,t,e,v,e,r} => glyphid:1234
```

so instead of rendering the string "whatever", the moment it sees the complete string "whatever" it substitutes the sequences with the single glyph found at internal glyph position 1234, which in this font "is" an icon (outlines are just outlines, but you, the human, identify it as an icon, and that's what matters) and renders that instead.

A much more detailed explanation can be found here: http://pomax.github.io/CFF-glyphlet-fonts/